# Why are characters inserted in my PHP link?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-routes

I created a module, but the link is not correct.

**My site now shows :**

```
 /store/2?0=/cgv
```

**The correct link should be :**

```
 /store/2/cgv
```

Why doesn't it work ? where is the error ?
What should I change in the code below, to get the link ?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_agree_cgv\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "agree_cgv",
 *   label = @Translation("Agree CGV"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class AgreeCGV extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => 800,
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::createFromRoute(
      $this->t('the general terms and conditions of business'),
      'entity.commerce_store.canonical',
      ['commerce_store' => $store_id, '/cgv'],
      $attributes
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['cgv'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @cgv.', ['@cgv' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

Comment: I have no idea about drupal, but this looks syntacticly wrong: `['commerce_store' => $store_id, '/cgv']` - I guess it should be `['commerce_store' => $store_id. '/cgv']` (a dot instead of the `,`, so that it'll concatanate and not add another array value.)

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, if I replace the comma with a dot, I have this error
 `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException : Parameter "commerce_store" for route "entity.commerce_store.canonical" must match "\d+" ("3/cgv" given) to generate a corresponding URL. dans Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (ligne 204 de /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).`

Comment: to me drupal is saying that it should be `['commerce_store' => $store_id]`, without the `/cgv`; which is not what you want. I'm afraid I cannot help any further (no idea about drupal...)

Comment: What is your definition for the route `entity.commerce_store.canonical`? It sounds like that did not include any such extra parameter to begin with.

Comment: @misorude https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x#comment-64172  J'ai trouvé ceci mais pas de réponse

Answer (score 0):

Because `$link` is not built correctly :

```
$link = Link::createFromRoute(
  $this->t('the general terms and conditions of business'), 
  'entity.commerce_store.canonical', 
  ['commerce_store' => $store_id, '/cgv'], # -> this is wrong
  $attributes
)->toString();
```

> $route_parameters: (optional) An associative array of parameter names
>   and values.

You did not specify any name for the 2nd route parameters, so the corresponding array key fallback to the first available numeric indice, that is `0`, meaning `[ '/cgv' ]` becomes `[ 0 => '/cgv' ]` and you don't get the link you expected.

I think (if I understood your issue correctly) what you need is to define in the first place that specific route handling cgv's for a given commerce_store, that is with the `/cgv` appended :

```
$route_collection = new RouteCollection();
$route = (new Route('/commerce_store/{commerce_store}/cgv'))
  ->addDefaults([
    '_controller' => $_controller,
    '_title_callback' => $_title_callback,
  ])
  ->setRequirement('commerce_store', '\d+')
  ->setRequirement('_entity_access', 'commerce_store.view');
$route_collection->add('entity.commerce_store.canonical.cgv', $route);
```

... so that you can build links based on that specific route :

```
$link = Link::createFromRoute(
  $this->t('the general terms and conditions of business'), 
  'entity.commerce_store.canonical.cgv',
  ['commerce_store' => $store_id],
  $attributes
)->toString();
```