# How to insert an ID into a string with PHP?

Tags: php, url, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I created a module for Drupal 8.6. I have a variable `$store_id` with the id of a store

How do I insert `$store_id` into the folowing link:

`Url::fromUri('internal:/store/?????/cgv', $attributes)`

For example when $store_id = 6 I want to get:

`internal:/store/6/cgv` as the argument to `Url::fromUri`

Comment: Doesn't `Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)` work? Note you need to change to `"` from `'` to get variable substitution.

Comment: @Nick Super, thank you it works ;-) I have an identical question, can be with you the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155040/why-are-characters-inserted-in-my-php-link she is different because she uses
 `Link::createFromRoute`

Comment: Sorry I don't know Drupal well enough to be able to answer your other question. Good luck.

Comment: Rephrased the question a little to clarify what is required

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per Nick's comment, just change it to:

`Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)`